# How do I convert a decimal number representing time to actual time in Crystal Reports 2008? Ex: "1.5" represents 1:30

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to edit an existing Crystal Report that shows time allowances for work orders. Budgeted Time / Actual Time / Remaining Time type deal.

These fields show up as not properly converting time from the data field for the report. The person who made the report has some formula for it already but I'm not sure what's it doing.

Formula: Standard Time

```
Stringvar array Std_Time := split(replace(cstr({WOMNT_CARD.STANDARD_HOURS_DURATION}),",",""),".");

val(Std_Time[1])*60+val(Std_Time[2])
```

The field used in the report is Sum of @Standard Time (Number).

How do I fix this so these numbers are properly converted?

Comment: I don't think `1.72` means `1 hour 72 minutes`. It means `1 hour +72% of an hour`, meaning `1 hour + (0.72*60) minutes`. ==> `1:43`

Comment: I've tried a couple different formulas I've seen posted and they either don't work at all or they return 0:0.

Comment: @ByteHamster You're current. That was an awful example. So, instead, Ex: 1.50 -> 1:30

Comment: I have never used Crystal Reports. But you need something like this: **Hours:** `Floor(1.5)` = `1`. **Minutes**: `(1.5 - Floor(1.5)) * 60` = `(1.5 - 1) * 60` = `0.5 * 60` = `30`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula that you have posted does the following:

First it converts the datatype of the `{WOMNT_CARD.STANDARD_HOURS_DURATION}` field to string by using the `cstr` function, the result is being stripped of commas with the `replace` function and the resulted string is being split into an array by using the dot character as the delimiter.

So, for the value 1.5 the `Std_Time` variable will hold the following

`Std_Time[1]` → 1

`Std_Time[2]` → 5

Finally it calculates the result by multiplying the first value of the first index with 60 and adds to it the value of the second index. The value 1.5 becomes 1 * 60 + 5 = 65

If the 1.5 must represent 1:30 then the last line must become

```
val(Std_Time[1]) * 60 + 60 * val(Std_Time[2]) / 10
```

because 60 * 5 / 10 = 30

or you can use for simplicity just the following

```
60 * val(replace(cstr({WOMNT_CARD.STANDARD_HOURS_DURATION}),",",""))
```

since 60 * 1.5 = 90